# Does an accidental enemy death count as a kill against the PEACE WALKER achievement?

Tags: achievements, metal-gear-solid-hd-collection, metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater

Does an accidental enemy death count as a kill? Specifically, if I tranq an enemy then he dies as a result of the action of another party (someone else shaking the bridge or an animal or something else), do I get a kill as a result? I'm going for the `PEACE WALKER` achievement for no kills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't cite a source however when I played through MGS3:HD I remember that shooting the enemies on the floating crafts in the swamp/river and having them crash counted as a kill so I want to say that the design is probably generally the same. Just save often and be very careful because MGS is a sneaky, sneaky series.

Comment: No pun intended. ;D

Comment: Don't claim that pun snuck up on you.